# App keeps filling logcat with this message: D/BubblePopupHelper:isShowingBubblePopup:false

Tags: java, android, logcat

My app is spamming the following message to logcat ~3 times per second: D/BubblePopupHelper:isShowingBubblePopup:false

When I close the app, the message stops appearing. I am not sure whether it is something important or not. Is there any way to fix it?? As you can probably see I am using Android Studio as my IDE.

Here is my DDMS:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you write `BubblePopupHelper`? If yes, what is it and where are you making this `Log.d()` call?

Comment: I am not making any Log.d() calls in my application whatsoever; the only log calls I make are some Log.v() calls which appear under very special circumstances... And no I have not written BubblePopupHelper anywhere in my app code...

Comment: I have the same problem, after some search I realized I get the message whenever I update a TextView (which is through a timer). Other people have reported similar problem

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to avoid this and many others, unless Google removes them from SDK. But you can filter to see messages of your interest by using the filtering feature of the LogCat if you organize your tags in a way that you can identify all of them with a Regex. 
For example if they all start with Braim, then Braim.* will include only them

[image]

Answer (score 1):

goto "editfilterconfiguration" in android tab and give logtag(regex) as [^D/BubblePopupHelper]. It will be filtered out.